# No more space in root partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, root

I know that there are loads of similar posts but none of them apparently solved my problem, sorry!

gparted:

[image]

`df -h`:

[image]

As you can see my root partition (sda5) is full and I really can't understand of what!
I already tried to clean my laptop with ubuntu-tweak, sudo apt-get autoremove --purge, apt-get clean, apt-get autoclean, I think that I removed also the old kernels, the trash and the root trash are empty...I don't know what else I might do! Thank to anyone who will try to help!

Comment: Your disk is kinda small, and it's kinda full. Start `Disk Usage Analyzer` from the Unity dashboard, and see if you can determine what's taking up space on your /dev/sda5 partition.

Answer (score 1):

Use `du -s` or a graphical utility to find out which directories take up the space. (If necessary, boot the installation DVD or flash drive and mount the root partition in /mnt or somewhere else.) Proceed until you find the unexpectedly large or numerous files, and report back.

```
sudo du -ms /* 2>/dev/null | sort -nr
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use du or ncdu.

For example du -sh * in the full partition :

```
# du -sh /*
```

It might take a while, and output some permissions errors if you are not root. It will display the size of each folder.

Or with ncdu :

```
# apt-get install ncdu
# ncdu /
```

Comment: Thanks every one using  `baobab`  (`Disk Usage Analizer`) I realised that for some unknown reason my backup folder which lives in a external hard disk was duplicated in sda5. It took almost 15 GiB of space! For the moment I solved deleting that big folder. I also noticed that the TexLive folder is almost 5 GiB! Anyone knows why is it so big? Can I delete it?